# Prove that $\bigcup\limits_{X \in \{A\}} X = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The problem I have with this is that it wants me to prove this using the following definition:

Let $C$ be a collection of sets. The union of $C$ is the set:
$$\bigcup\limits_{X \in C} X = \{ x | (\exists X)(X \in C \land x \in X)\} $$

This is a first for me because I always just assumed this notation was simply that: a notation. It's supposed to just be a short-hand written way of writing $X_1 \cup X_2 \cup ..... \cup X_n$. But to prove? I have no idea it just seems so trivial  I have no idea how to actually start without just writing $A$ and being done with it. Could someone help me make sense of it?

Comment: I think the subject line is fine: it says $\bigcup_{X\in\{A\}} X$, not $\bigcup_{X\in A} X$.

Comment: As you point out, the definition of $x\in\bigcup_{X\in\{A\}} X$ is
$$
\exists X\colon X\in\{A\} \land x\in X.
$$
You need to prove that this holds if and only if $x\in A$. Yes, this is a pretty easy thing to prove; that's why this is a great example for practicing the necessary structures of proofs and how they follow from the definitions involved. (Note also that $X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_n$ is fine when $C$ is finite, but what about when $C$ is infinite? uncountable? That's when the $\bigcup_{X\in C}$ notation really shines.)

Comment: I know it can also be used for infinite amount of sets, I  should have been clearer on what I thought it was. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Follow your nose.

We have:
$$
\bigcup\limits_{X \in C} X = \{ x | (\exists X)(X \in C \land x \in X)\} \tag{1}
$$

Letting $C = \{A\}$, we have $$
X \in C \iff X = A \tag{2}
$$
(because that's what enumeration of a set means). So
\begin{align}
\bigcup\limits_{X \in C} X 
& = \{ x | (\exists X)(X \in C \land x \in X)\} & \text{definition 1}\\
& = \{ x | (\exists X)(X= A \land x \in X)\} & \text{observation 2}\\
& = \{ x | (\exists X)(X= A \land x \in A)\} & \text{substitution}\\
& = \{ x | (x \in A)\} & \text{$X = A$ shows that there exists $X$ with $X = A$}\\
& = \{ x | x \in A\} & \text{remove parens}\\
& = A & \text{definition of "$\{\ldots \mid \ldots\}$" notation}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Much thanks for this. I see the pattern of these sort of proofs now. I appreciate it I was getting so flustered thinking "what proof?! it's just notation!!".

Comment: My arguments for the last few steps are shaky -- I don't really do logic or set theory. But as if often the case, unwinding definitions makes things easier...and also shows you why the definitions are pretty well-crafted, as @GregMartin pointed out in his comment on the question.